# Do continuous functions preserve Lebesgue Measure to any degree?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

So I'm trying to prove a homework problem, and as a lemma I'd like the following to be true, although I'm not sure it is:

If $f$ continuous and $\mu(f(A)) = c >0$ then for all continuous and $\|g-f\|< \epsilon$ then $|\mu(g(A)) - c|<\epsilon$.

If necessary, we can take $A$ compact (it is, in my problem). Moreover, the final restriction isn't necessary for my problem. If $\mu(f(A))>0$ then I'd like to be able to show that in some ball around $f$ (in the standard function norm), $\mu(g(A))>0$. This would suffice for my purposes.

Here we take $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure and functions being continuous mappings of $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$.

I tried something, but it ended up being a false proof. It used compactness to extract a finite number of intervals covering $f(A)$ and $g(A)$, but I couldn't send the differences between their measures to zero uniformly.

Comment: So, you'd like $\mu_A:C[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ to be continuous? (Where $\mu_A(f) = \mu(f(A))$).

Comment: Yes, precisely. I take it it's false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance the Cantor function takes the Cantor set (a set of zero measure) to a set of full measure.  Its continuous so you can approximate it uniformly with smooth functions (in fact, polynomials) by Stone-Weierstrass.  A differentiable map must map null sets to null sets.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: That'll do it. Dang. Okay, thanks!

Comment: Sure. I knew the cantor function had to be the counterexample, but it was fun thinking about why. good luck with the hw problem.

Comment: The cantor function popped up and was actually an example of our intuition for the problem. Wasn't aware of the differentiability theorem though!